# How to get data from DialogFragment to a Fragment?

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments

Imagine, I have *FragmentA* from which I *startDialogFragment* (there are `EditText` in box). How to can I get back the value from the `EditText` to *FragmentA*? I try to make something like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment) but I was not successful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966605/fragments-how-to-start-dialog-from-fragment/17968000#17968000. here returning boolean value instead return the edittext value. Or use a interface.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The `Fragment.onActivityResult()` method is useful in this situation. It takes `getTargetRequestCode()`, which is a code you set up between fragments so they can be identified. In addition, it takes a request code, normally just `0` if the code worked well, and then an `Intent`, which you can attach a string too, like so

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("STRING_RESULT", str);
```

Also, the `setTargetFragment(Fragment, requestCode)` should be used in the fragment that the result is being sent from to identify it. Overall, you would have code in the requesting fragment that looks like this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogFragment();
dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, REQUEST_CODE);
dialogFragment.show();
```

The class to send data (the DialogFragment) would use this Fragment we just defined to send the data:

```
private void sendResult(int REQUEST_CODE) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putStringExtra(EDIT_TEXT_BUNDLE_KEY, editTextString);
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
        getTargetRequestCode(), REQUEST_CODE, intent);
}
```

To receive the data, we use this type of class in the Fragment which initially started the DialogFragment:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Make sure fragment codes match up 
    if (requestCode == DialogFragment.REQUEST_CODE) {
        String editTextString = data.getStringExtra(
            DialogFragment.EDIT_TEXT_BUNDLE_KEY);
```

At this point, you have the string from your `EditText` from the `DialogFragment` in the parent fragment. Just use the `sendResult(int)` method in your `TextChangeListener()` anonymous class so that the text is sent when you need it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for this solution... Can you help me please? Why my onActivityResult() method can't capture result from my dialog fragment? When I have the same code... Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the right way to pass the result back to the fragment! Thanks for the example!

Comment: Small correction in the code (we have to use Activity.RESULT_OK): 
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
dismiss();

Comment: This solution is deprecated with Api-28 . see updated approach : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71758800/2267723

Answer (score 4):

Assume a situation that you are uploading some file to server , on clicking of upload button a dialog should open,prompting for title and optional tag.And the dialog itself containing 2 buttons say cancel and continue.

make the UI as you wish by using layout xml file.

then create one class that extending DialogFragment. inflate the layout and initialize views inside onCreateView() method.

Inside that class create one interface

```
 public interface uploadDialogInterface

   {
       public void senddata(String title, String tag);
   }

    uploadDialogInterface interfaceObj;
    String title="";
    String tag=" ";
```

And the important thing is you need to override onAttach() method

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context=context;
    interfaceObj= (uploadDialogInterface) getTargetFragment();
}
```

And in the on Button click call the interface method like

```
     @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id=v.getId();
    if(id== R.id.vB_fud_cancel)
    {
        dismiss();
    }
    else if(id== R.id.vB_fud_upload)
    {
        title=mVideotitle.getText().toString();
        tag=mOptionaltag.getText().toString();
        if(mVideotitle.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Snackbar.make(mVideotitle,"Please enter the video title", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }else
        {
            interfaceObj.senddata(title,tag);
            dismiss();

        }
    }
}
```

And inside the Fragment or activity from which you are launching the dialog should contain setTargetFragment attribute.

```
private void callUploadDialog()
{
    UploadDialogFragment fragment = new UploadDialogFragment();
    fragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_in);
    fragment.show(ft, "UploadDialogFragment");
    fragment.setCancelable(false);
}
```

And finally you should implement the interface (that was declared inside the dialog fragment) and override the method

```
@Override
public void senddata(String title,String optionaltag) {
    this.videoTitle=title;
    this.optionalTag=optionaltag;

}
```

I think this post will be helpful for those who are using dialog fragment for the first time . I was struggled to find the solution . And hopefully this will solve someone's problem in the future. 
(Sorry for the language)

Comment: And if you rotate after the dialog is opened? Won't that make that interface object reference the old fragment (the one before rotation?). Don't think this will work ok

Answer (score 4):

One of the better and simpler ways to do this is using Android ViewModel.

This helps in easier sharing of data, without the need of sending any data across fragments. You could do this not only for DialogFragments, but also for normal Fragments.

Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Here is what I did

**My ViewModel looks as below**

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class PlayerViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Player> selectedPlayer = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<Player> getSelectedPlayer() {
        return selectedPlayer;
    }

    public void selectPlayer(Player player) {
        selectedPlayer.setValue(player);
    }
}
```

In the Fragment where I select a Player, **I use the following code in the onCreate method to bind the ViewModel**

```
playerViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(PlayerViewModel.class);
```

When a specific Player is selected, use the following *(You can use an ArrayAdapter, DialogFragment's selector or anything you want to display list of players)*

```
playerViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(PlayerViewModel.class);
```

And finally, **in the fragment where you need to show the Player information**, do the following in the onCreate method

```
PlayerViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(PlayerViewModel.class);
model.getSelectedPlayer().observe(this, new Observer<Player>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Player selPlayer) {
        if (selPlayer != null)
            player = selPlayer;
            populateData();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Confirmed working!! Specially when using the new Navigation components library, it's not possible to do it using startActivityForResult.

Issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79672220

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the data from the dialog back to the activity via a callback method, then have the activity give that data back to the fragment you want it to go to. Just a quick example:

```
public void datFromDialog(String data){
    MyFragment mf = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(r.id.frag);

    mf.iWantNewData(data);
}
```

Comment: Please,can you explain it more or get more full exaple

Comment: look here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: you dont communicate between fragment directly, the activity is suppose to do all the communication between fragments. Fragments should not know that any other fragment exists. So basically it works like this. A button is clicked in a fragment that send a callback the the activity to start a dialog. Dialog is up whatever need to be done in there is done and another button is clicked there to send data back to the activity in which the activity will update the other fragment with new data

Comment: @tyczj how to do the same for childfragment? which doesn't have id?

Answer (score 0):

What you want, according to [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment,%20int))...

Answer (score 0):

**This method ensures that the calling fragment implements the onChangeListener of the dialog.**

FragmentA (calling fragment):

```
MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("data", data);
f.setArguments(args);
// Set the calling fragment for this dialog.
f.setTargetFragment(FragmentA.this, 0);
f.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragment");
```

MyDialogFragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public OnChangeListener onChangeListener;

    interface OnChangeListener{
        void onChange(Data data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the calling fragment and ensure that it implements onChangeListener.
        try {
            onChangeListener = (OnChangeListener) getTargetFragment();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(
                "The calling Fragment must implement MyDialogFragment.onChangeListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .....
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Send the data to the calling fragment.
                onChangeListener.onChange(data);
            }
        });
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dialogFragment.setTargetFragment is deprecated, see : [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)

> Instead of using a target fragment to pass results, the fragment requesting a result should use FragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(String, LifecycleOwner, FragmentResultListener) to register a FragmentResultListener with a requestKey using its parent fragment manager. The fragment delivering a result should then call FragmentManager.setFragmentResult(String, Bundle) using the same requestKey. Consider using setArguments to pass the requestKey if you need to support dynamic request keys.

Here is a simple implementation :

- Call from host Fragment

  ```
        val dialog = MockDialog.newInstance(
            "requestKey")

        dialog.show(
            childFragmentManager, MockDialog.TAG
        )
  ```
- In MockDialog (which extends DialogFragment):

  ```
    dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_yes) { _, _ ->
        parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResult(
            arguments!!.getString(DIALOG_REQUEST_PARAM)!!,// which is "requestKey"
            //add data to bundle
            bundleOf("result" to "any data")
        )
    }
  ```
- Get result on host Fragment:

  ```
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(
                "requestKey", this
            ) { requestKey, result ->
                // you data here 
                val data = result.getString("result", null)
            }
        }
  ```

Base-line : you need to pass your "requestKey" and pass it back to host-fragment

Good luck,'.