# How to make DialogFragment call a method inside another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have a tabbed activity that shows a fragment by a viewpager, as usual.
This fragment have a list.

One of the actions of the user shows a dialogfragment to user insert a new item in this list.

I show the dialogfragment with edittexts to user create a new item.

**The question is: how can I insert this item on the viewpagers' fragment list?**

From any fragment I can call getActivity() to access the activity, but how access another fragment that is being shown behind the dialogfragment?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment with the List items - `FragmentA`
Dialog - `NewItemDialogFragment`

The method you're missing is [setTargetFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment,%20int)). While building your `NewItemDialogFragment`, invoke this method passing the `FragmentA` as the target fragment for your dialog.
Later, you can access the `FragmentA` instance by calling [getTargetFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment()) inside `NewItemDialogFragment` and cast it to the `FragmentA` and add newly created item.

Alternatively, you can create the contract interface between the `FragmentA` and the `NewItemDialogFragment`

Comment: Great. Thanks for your answer, i believe that is the correct way according to android developers.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to get the **results from the dialogfragment** (*what the user has inserted on the dialogfragment edit-texts*)  and use this in the fragment that called the dialogfragment (to add as new item to the list) - in that case, the [selected answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025425/how-to-get-data-from-dialogfragment-to-a-fragment) solves this problem - also I think [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Joev-/5695813) is a good resource to reference.
In your case, I also think implementing some sort of a custom listener/callback as they did in this Gist is a good idea. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event bus for this.

http://square.github.io/otto/

This is an example of usage:

```
Bus bus = new Bus();

bus.post(new AnswerAvailableEvent(42));

@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(AnswerAvailableEvent event) {
    // TODO: React to the event somehow!
}

bus.register(this); // In order to receive events, a class instance needs to register with the bus.
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought in this lib but I wanted some native solution.