# is it possible to send data from dialog fragment to fragment related to activity and how?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

In my application I have a dialog fragment which opens first before launching of MainActivity. When some data is entered in that dialog fragment and click confirmed I need to send some value (means a double value) to a fragment(Main).

My main activity consists of view pager which has two fragments. one is fragment(Main).. i have to send the data to my dialog fragment to the fragment(main)

The fragment(Main) is attached to MainActivity by viewpager.
I have tried by sending the value to fragment(Main) by using Intents and bundle.
referred the sites to pass data between fragments.

while by using Intents it showing the exception unable to explicit have you declared in android Manifest

while by trying with bundle it getting exception bundle is null.

from these two exceptions I have got is it possible to send the data..
can any body help and give suggestion.

here is my dialog fragment:

```
public class InputFragment extends DialogFragment {



public InputFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input, container, false);
    final EditText ed = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    final Button b1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    final Button b2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!ed.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                    int input = Integer.valueOf(ed.getText().toString());
                    double out = input / 24.0;
                    out = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.0").format(out));
                    Intent m = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainScreen.class);
                    m.putExtra("res", out);
                    getActivity().startActivity(m);

                } else if (rb2.isChecked()) {
                    int input = Integer.valueOf(ed.getText().toString());
                    double out = ((input * 2 / 3) * 0.029574);
                    out = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.0").format(out));
                    Intent m = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainScreen.class);
                    m.putExtra("res", out);
                    getActivity().startActivity(m);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

fragment that receive data (Main):

```
public class MainScreen extends Fragment {

double ram;
TextView gls;
MainScreen mainScreen;

public MainScreen() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_screen, container, false);
    mainScreen = this;
    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.res);
    Intent r = getActivity().getIntent();
    double res = r.getDoubleExtra("res", 0);
    String result = Double.toString(res);
    textView.setText(result);


    ram = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString());
    gls = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.glasses);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DiaFragment df = new DiaFragment();
            df.setCallingFragment(mainScreen);
            df.show(getFragmentManager(),"Frag");
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Above I tried by intent,

by using bundle:
in my fragment(Main)

```
Bundle mbundle = mainScreen.getArguments();
    double res = mbundle.getDouble("res",0);
    String result = Double.toString(res);
    textView.setText(result);
```

dialog fragment:

```
InputFragment inputFragment = new InputFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putDouble("res",out);
                        inputFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from DialogFragment to a Fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025425/how-to-get-data-from-dialogfragment-to-a-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

1.create interface :

```
public interface OnReceivedData {
    public void onDataReceived(Objects objects);
}
```

2.create Dialog :

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment {
    private OnReceivedData mData;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mData=(OnReceivedData) activity;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // create dialog
        senDataToActivity();
    }

    private void senDataToActivity() {
        mData.onDataReceived("your object");
    }
}
```

3.call dialog :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnReceivedData  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    private void opneDialog(){
        //
    }
    @Override
    public void onDataReceived(Objects objects) {
        // receded data
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, the dialog is opened by activity but the received data is be used in the fragment (Main). means here my main activity as a page viewer which consists two fragments..In that one of the fragment (Main) needs the data of dialog fragment..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a fragment like this:

```
Intent m = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainScreen.class);
```

Instead this:

```
MainScreen fragment = new MainScreen();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(id, fragment , "MainScreen");
ft.addToBackStack("");
ft.commit();
```