# Wrong 1st argument type. required "android.app.fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem when using `DialogFragment`

```
DialogFragment dialog = new DateDialog(this);
dialog.setTargetFragment(this,1);
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Where `this` caused the error. my class extends `FragmentActivity`.

[image]

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905312/receive-result-from-dialogfragment), but so far, cannot apply on my code. what do i do wrong ?

This is my class :

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class RegisterActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnDateSetListener
{

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message and/or stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure you are using the correct DialogFragment:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

```
   ↳    android.app.Fragment
       ↳    android.app.DialogFragment
```

versus

```
   ↳    android.support.v4.app.Fragment
       ↳    android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
```

It's easy to import the wrong class. Just look at which version of FragmentActivity you are using and pick the corresponding DialogFragment.

Comment: I share my class and import class. so the correct one is to import which one ?

Comment: You're importing: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

So, use the .v4 Fragment.