# Raise event from DialogFragment to caller

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on a Xamaran.Android project and try to implement a DialogFragment. I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_0s9IslwYs) in order to set the Popup.

Here is the code of my DialogFragment :

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    var view =  inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.WordChooser, container, false);

    SubmitButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.SubmitButton);
    SubmitButton.Click += SubmitButton_Click;

    return view;
}

private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

And here is my Activity caller :

```
private void FooButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var trasaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    WordChooser wordChooserDialog = new WordChooser();

    wordChooserDialog.Show(trasaction, "word chooser fragment");
}
```

I do not know how to set value from my DialogFragment to my Activity and close the DialogFragment.
I tryed to use the second answer of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905312/receive-result-from-dialogfragment) but wasn't able to use `getActivity();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getXYZ` and `setXYZ` get c#yfied. This means Xamarin is mapping getters and setters into properties. In your case `getActivity` is the getter of the property `Activity` of `DialogFragment`.

To pass data, you could

- add a method `DoSomething` to your activity
- cast the `Activity` to `MainActivity`or what ever your calling activity is
- call `DoSomething` from your click listener

**Dialog**

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((MainActivity) Activity).DoSomething("something");
    Dismiss();
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    //...

    public void DoSomething(string something)
    {

    }
}
```

There are some other possible solutions, like

- passing a callback to your Fragment
- adding a event to your Fragment
- ...

**Important**

Do not forget do deregister your event handlers. Every `+=` should have a `-=`counterpart somewhere in your code. E.g. `SubmitButton.Click -= SubmitButton_Click` before you close the Fragment.

Comment: So I do not understand why on this Xamarin documentation [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.DialogFragment/), there is a line of code like that : `((FragmentDialog)getActivity()).showDialog();` ?

Comment: If you read carefully, you see, that these are **java examples**. I guess Xamarin is scraping the documentation from the google documentation. Beside the documentation stuff: Does my answer solve your problem?