# Android: Dialogue Fragment, Callbacks and Fragments. Design implimentation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am calling a Fragment Dialogue from a Fragment, and when I try to impliment a callback it isn't calling back to the Fragment, I think it is calling back to the Activity. I believe this is by design from Google, is there anyway around that? How can couple the Dialogue Fragment to the Fragment?

My code is as follows;

Dialogue Fragment

```
public class CustomDatePicker extends DialogFragment {

    private DateListener listener;

    ...

    public interface DateListener {
        void onDateComplete();
    }

}
```

Fragment

```
public class User extends Fragment implements CustomDatePicker.DateListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onDateComplete() {
        Log.i("TEST", "onDateComplete: " + date);
    }

}
```

Comment: How and where do you call the listener? And where do you set it?

Comment: @ElDuderino, I don't. How would I do that?

Comment: Well just because you have one class implement an interface doesn't mean it will receive any events. Have a look at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6270150/2001247), it will explain how listeners work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, based off of comments and answers was the following.

Dialogue Fragment;

```
public class CustomDatePicker extends DialogFragment {

private DateListener listener;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

Button btnSave = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.save);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDate();
            dismiss();
            listener.onDateComplete();
        }
    });

...

}

...

public interface DateListener {
    void onDateComplete();
}

}
```

Fragment;

```
public class User extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

    CustomDatePicker customDatePicker = new CustomDatePicker();
    customDatePicker.setListener(new CustomDatePicker.DateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateComplete() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

...

}

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those purposes you can use `setTargetFragment()`and `onActivityResult()`.
Check this: [Receive result from DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905312/receive-result-from-dialogfragment) or [Callback to a Fragment from a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment). In this case you dont need any interfaces.

Interfaces:

```
public class CustomDatePicker extends DialogFragment {

    private DateListener listener;

    public interface DateListener {
        void onDateComplete(long date);
    }

    public void setListener(DateListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void sendToFragment(long value) {  //value you want to pass
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onDateComplete(value);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class User extends Fragment implements CustomDatePicker.DateListener  {

    public void showDialog(){
        CustomDatePicker datePicker = new CustomDatePicker();
        datePicker.setListener(this); // since User fragment implements it

        ...

        datePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "TAG");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateComplete(long date) {
        Log.d("Interface", "onDateComplete: " + date);
    }
}
```

Call `sendToFragment()` with your value where you need, hope this help.

Comment: That creates a tightly coupled architecture. What if I wish to reuse the `DialogFragment` elsewhere?

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

instead of implementing your listener to your fragment get a new instance of your dialog fragment and new your listener when you want to call it
add newInstance to your dialog fragment like this:

```
public static CustomDatePicker newInstance(DateListener listener) {
    return  new CustomDatePicker();
}
```

and show your dialog fragment in this way:

```
CustomDatePicker.newInstance(new CustomDatePicker.DateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDialogPositiveListener(DialogFragment dialog) {
}).show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

so you can get result in your code